# android box shadow troubles

Tags: android, kotlin

Here's my code to create a box shadow around an imageView. It should look like the attached but it doesn't. Can someone please help?[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

For it, you can use buildin feature **Create Shadows and Clip Views** for this shadow. Visit for details: [**LINK**](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping). According to this document,

> Material design introduces elevation for UI elements. Elevation helps
>   users understand the relative importance of each element and focus
>   their attention on the task at hand.
>   The elevation of a view, represented by the Z property, determines the
>   visual appearance of its shadow: views with higher Z values cast
>   larger, softer shadows. Views with higher Z values occlude views with
>   lower Z values; however, the Z value of a view does not affect the
>   view's size.

The Z value for a view has two components:

- **Elevation**: The static component.
- **Translation:** The dynamic component used for animations.

`Z = elevation + translationZ`

[image]

You can add these 2 for the shadow.

```
android:elevation="5dp"
android:translationZ="12dp"
```

`android:elevation` range `2dp` to `8dp` is better. [my opinion] -> more `dp` means more **blur** and wide **shadow**

`android:translationZ` range `8dp` to `15dp` is better. [my opinion]

If there are multiple views in the layout, you should add `margin` to feel that shadow. Try to keep the same margin `db` as `elevation`'s `dp`